# Сохранение кода VBA при записи xlsm из Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, vba

Просьба дать совет, какую библиотеку python предпочтительно использовать для решения задачи.

Есть шаблон Excel в формате xlsxm c легаси-кодом на VBA. Шаблон содержит оформление, навигацию и прочее, что не оптимально переписывать заново на Python. Есть необходимость из Python экспортировать в диапазон Excel массива данных из Pandas Dataframe.

Проблема: `xlsxwriter` не поддерживает добавление данных в существующий шаблон, а только перезаписывает файл. `openpyxl` не поддерживает формат xlsm и, как следствие, отрезает VBA код из шаблона.

Comment: Добавил пример excel файла с простым примером оформления и вложенным макросом на VBA.
[ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e2opkWLmLAMIxsZMv7Y5Q-P6Ddja_CU7)

Comment: задача - добавить новые строки в "Лист1"?

Comment: Обновить диапазон на Листе1, сохранив макросы и форматирование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример - для простоты я изменил значение одной ячейки - `"B2"` на `1000`:

```
In [105]: from openpyxl import load_workbook

In [106]: filename = r"D:\download\1.xlsm"

In [107]: wb = load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
# NOTE: -----------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

In [108]: ws = wb.active

In [109]: ws["B2"].value = 1000

In [110]: wb.save(filename)
```

После сохранения - кнопки с макросами работают и форматирование не изменилось.